# Can't get place image into another row in Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have two images with equal sizes. I have a grid with one column and two rows. I'd like to move one image into the second row, but no matter what I do, it just won't move down there. What can I do?
Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
        }
        .flex{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: space-evenly;
        }

        .flex img:nth-of-type(2){
            grid-row: 2/3;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="flex">
            <img src="resources/images/image1.png">
            <img src="resources/images/image2.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You messed up grid and flex. Your `<div class="flex">` expects two elements for rows. And you got only one (`<div class="flex">`). Try to remove that div.

```
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: How do I add flex to those elements then? For centering purposes

Comment: grid can also centering elements similarly to flex
`justify-items: center;`
`align-items: center;`

Comment: grid has `justify-content: space-evenly;` and `justify-content: space-around;`
Check this http://grid.malven.co/

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you? I have displayed the images in a list.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .container{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
        }
        .flex{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: space-evenly;
            list-style: none;
             display: inline;
        }

        .flex img:nth-of-type(2){
            grid-row: 2/3;
        }
        ul {
        white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
            <ul class="flex">
                <li><img src="resources/images/image1.png"></li>
                <li><img src="resources/images/image1.png"></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your `.container` element creates a **grid formatting context** that the 2 `img` elements are not participating in because they are child elements of the `ul` element with the class of `.flex` which is participating in the grid formatting context created by `.container` so for example, if you were to add a sibling element after the `ul` element in your markup it would follow the rules of the grid you have outlined.

If you want the `img` elements to be formatted using the grid template that you have outlined on the `.container` element, change you HTML markup and make the `img` elements **direct** children of the `.container` element.

In terms of centering, you can center the elements within a grid item (child element of the grid container) using the property and value pair `justify-content: center` which you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-items).

Below is an example of what you want:

```css
.image {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.image:first-child {
  background: firebrick;
}
.image:last-child {
  background: royalblue;
}

/*
========================================
Ignore the above rules
========================================

*/

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>
```